# An efficient way of checking boxes using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to unwrap two boxes connected to two buttons out of three. Then within the two boxes there are few fields to check or uncheck options.

With the below scripts i can check the desired boxes connect to first two buttons but the thing is the way I did the whole operation is quite untidy. How Ican I do it in an efficient way?

The script I've tried with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://urbantoronto.ca/database/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#filter_status_arrow"))).click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#check_pre_construction"))).click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#check_complete"))).click()

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#filter_project_type_arrow"))).click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#check_condo"))).click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#check_co_op"))).click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#check_house"))).click()

driver.quit()
```

By default [the buttons look like this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n4es8q6tl96jit8/image2.jpg?dl=0).

When I select the desired fields, they [look like this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/snhg0al6kkl8xu1/image1.jpg?dl=0).

How can I do it in an efficient way?

Comment: well, it depends on what you mean by efficient.  If you want to click each individual button, your solution is about as efficient as it gets in terms of execution time.  If you wanted the code to be tidier you could just make a list of the css selectors that need to be clicked and loop through that.  If you wanted the code to be faster, just snag the JSON straight from the source code of the database page and use the `json` library to filter from there.

Comment: Yes n1c9, you are right. I meant to do the same thing using loops but can't find an idea to do so. As for the json link I could not find one using dev tools. However, I checked out source code but couldn't discover it either. It should be there, though.

Comment: It's in a variable named `projects`, right after the `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//urbantoronto.ca/sites/all/themes/urbane/favicon.ico" /></script>` bit. I tried to copy & paste it to pastebucket but it was too large.

Comment: Oh I see!! I've already come that across but there is no link connected to that project leading to the json stuffs.

Comment: The content of that projects variable *is* the JSON - it's all loaded right from the page, not from an outside source.  If it is from an outside source, usually looking at the network tab and filtering for XHR requests helps de-mystify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure what you mean by *"efficient way"*.

Try below solution and let me know in case some improvements required:

```
driver.get("http://urbantoronto.ca/database/")

# Use @id of filter as key, @ids of check-box as values
filters = {"filter_status": ["pre_construction", "under_construction", "complete"],
           "filter_project_type": ["condo", "hotel", "institutional"]}

for filter_item in filters:
    driver.find_element_by_id("%s_arrow" % filter_item).click()
    for checkbox in filters[filter_item]:
        driver.find_element_by_id(filter_item).find_element_by_id("check_%s" % checkbox).click()
```

Comment: Yes, this is the one I was trying to do. Thanks again sir. I may need to post another question related to this. I'm facing stale element issue while crawling individual links.